# Orthogonal Matrices and their determinant

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I have a doubt: I know that **if** a matrix is orthogonal, then it's determinant is either 1 or -1. What I'd like to know is if having a determinant equal to either 1 or -1 necessarily implies that a matrix is orthogonal.

Thank you!

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider $\begin{pmatrix}
 1&2\\0&1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly not. Take any invertible matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ where $n\geq 2$. Now, take the matrix

$$B=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{|\det(A)|}}\cdot A$$

Then the determinant of $B$ is $1$ or $-1$, but $B$ doesn't need to be an orthogonal matrix, since if $BB^T=B^TB=I$, that would mean that $A^TA$ is also a scalar multiple of $I$, and this is surely not the case for all matrices!